# How to apply the bootstrap grid system for dynamic expanding div instead of window

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am facing the problem to apply the bootstrap grid style to the dynamic expanding div.

While button clicking the container div expanding but medium grid like style not applying when it reaches to the medium width.

Here my code to apply the bootstrap style.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

$(".my").removeClass("container");
$(".my").addClass("container");
$("#chg").width($("#chg").width()+10);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button>Display the width of div</button>

<div class="my container" id="chg" style="width:300px;background-color:pink;position:absolute;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you want to do? you want maximum expandable width to be your applied style width?

Comment: Here I have a bootstrap medium style with 'col-md-2'. I need when the div expanding to the bootstrap medium limit size. the 'col-md-2' type grid show there.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this slightly wrong. The Bootstrap Grid System used Media Queries, which are based on your entire viewport width, not the width relative to the container. So in your code snippet above, if you hit 'Full screen' (even without pressing the button to make it wider) you'll see your `md` styles have been applied (making the text squished, which you really don't want).

I'm sure there are some clever ways to do what you want with CSS, but I'm afraid I'm not sure, certainly what you are trying to do here using the Grid system is not what Bootstrap was designed to do. You may have to build some custom Javascript to measure the width of your element and change the classes dynamically that way.